# txt file doesn't contain the results?

Tags: python, try-catch

Here is a typical exception process but it doesn't write it to the file later. What could be wrong?

Summary:
The `with` statement is used to write the files that are not existent. In this case they are not being written to the txt file. Possible solution would be to simply change how the writing process is happening.

```
AST = []
ASTOTA = []

folder = path.Path(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\testn")
with open('log.txt', 'w') as fw:
    for shpfile in glob.iglob('/*/*/Desktop/testn/*/*/*'):
        try:
            df = geopandas.read_file(shpfile).assign(col = get_folder(shpfile))
            if shpfile.endswith('AST.shp'):
                AST.append(df)
            else:
                ASTOTA.append(df)
        except FionaValueError as ex:
            if not os.listdir(shpfile):
                fw.write(f'{shpfile} is empty' + '\n') <- Here is where 
                                                          should write to the txt file
```

The position of the `fw.write` is obviously the wrong part because if I replace it with a print statement it still doesn't show anything even though there **are** things to write because some folders are indeed empty.

Comment: Did you try catching every error, i.e. replacing `FionaValueError` with simply `Exception`? It will be useful to print the exception if it occurs (`print(ex)`).

Comment: Does the iterator `glob.iglob('/*/*/Desktop/testn/*/*/*')` return any files?

Comment: Everything you said is covered.The specific error is the only that should appear.It is tested. The only possible problem I think it may be is trying and catching it in every if and else line which i tried but didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop iterates over all the files in a directory - if there are no files in the directory, that loop will not run at all, so it will never reach the missing file logic. Perhaps something like the following, which checks if there are any files in the directory and writes to a new one if not:

```
# check if the directory is empty
if len(os.listdir('/home/varun/temp') ) == 0:    
    fw.write(f'{shpfile} is empty' + '\n')

for shpfile in glob.iglob('/*/*/Desktop/testn/*/*/*'):
        try:
            df = geopandas.read_file(shpfile).assign(col =     get_folder(shpfile))    if shpfile.endswith('AST.shp'):
                AST.append(df)
            else:
                ASTOTA.append(df)
        except FionaValueError as ex:
            # whatever way you want to handle this exception
```

Comment: it has to write the files that are not present as it does the loop. Look how it appears  in the code.